# WiFi Power Management Keeps Turning On

Tags: wireless

I needed to speed up my Wifi, so I ran `sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 power off` which turned off power management. To check, I ran `iwconfig` and it was successfully turned off. But after restarting, the power management was back on! Why does it turn back on when I specifically turned it off?

It also turns back on when I unplug the charger and such.

Here's the output of `iwconfig`:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Fullam-2.4G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.745 GHz  Access Point: 76:AC:B9:10:0B:5C   
          Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=30 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=35/70  Signal level=-75 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:36   Missed beacon:0
```

How do I make power management stay off?

Answer (score 1):

Try editing `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` and changing the 3 to a 2 (make it look like the following):

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
```

Reboot.

Comment: I have already tried this and it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try using tlp and changing the settings?

Comment: yes, I've tried that already.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 with Intel Wireless AC 8265. It is sufficient to restart NetworkManager with `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service` instead of reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Reboot and check:

```
iwconfig
```

**EDIT**: This is highly experimental. I have not seen this on AU before and you will be testing it for us! If it is not successful, it can be reverted in one command:

Please do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tlp
sudo nano /etc/tlp.conf
```

Change these lines:

```
# WiFi power saving mode: on=enable, off=disable; not supported by all adapters.
#WIFI_PWR_ON_AC=off
#WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=on
```

...to read:

```
# WiFi power saving mode: on=enable, off=disable; not supported by all adapters.
WIFI_PWR_ON_AC=off
WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=off
```

Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x followed by Enter). Next, do:

```
sudo tlp start
```

Confirm that the settings are active, run the following command:

```
tlp-stat --rfkill
```

You should see Power Management = off.

**EDIT 2**: I suggest that you try another method. Please open a terminal and do:

```
printf '%s\n' '#!/bin/bash' 'exit 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/rc.local
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service
```

Add the following:

```
[Unit]
 Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility
 ConditionPathExists=/etc/rc.local

[Service]
 Type=forking
 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start
 TimeoutSec=0
 StandardOutput=tty
 RemainAfterExit=yes
 SysVStartPriority=99

[Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Proofread carefully. Save and exit nano.

```
sudo systemctl enable rc-local
sudo systemctl start rc-local
sudo systemctl status rc-local
```

If all is correct, it should report that it is active. Next, do:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Above the line 'exit 0' add the following:

```
/usr/sbin/iwconfig wlp2s0 power off
```

Proofread carefully. Save and exit nano.

Is there any improvement?

Comment: I have already tried changing it from a 3 to a 2 but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What is the driver? `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

Comment: kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci. I'm using ath10k

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: @chhili555 I tried what you said to do, but it still doesn't work. After unplugging the charger it still goes back on. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have another highly experimental edit in a few moments. Since tlp didn't work, you may safely: `sudo apt purge tlp`

Comment: I tried the second edit. It didn't work, so I disabled the service and deleted the new files that I created (rc.local, rc-local.service). Anything else I can do?

Comment: I am sorry that I have no further suggestions.

Comment: This works but you must enable the tlp service using systemctl and enable it in the config file.