# Why is there a file "wireless-info" in my home directory?

Tags: wireless

I was doing a bunch of stuff with making my internet connection faster, and now I see a file in my home directory called "wireless-info." I don't know if tlp added it there or if it was one of the experimental things I tried, but is it safe to delete? Here's what the file looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Copyright (c) 2012
#
# Authors: Wild Man, Krytarik
# Helpers: chili555
#
# This script gathers the infos necessary for troubleshooting a wireless
# connection and saves them in a text file, wrapping it in an archive if it
# exceeds the 19.5 kB size limit for ".txt" attachments on the Ubuntu Forums.
#
##############################################################################
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#

SCRIPTDATE="2020-1-25 05:34 +0200"
FILEBASE="wireless-info"
OUTPUTDIR="$PWD"
OUTPUTDIRFB="/tmp"

MODMATCHES="(air|ar5|at7|ath[^3]?|b43|bcma|brcm|carl|ipw|iwl|ndis|r(818|8192[eu]|871|92su)|8(188|189|192|723|812)[acde][esu]|rt[23567]|rtl|ssb|wl|(cfg|mac)80211)"
LSMODMATCHES="(wmi|(dell|ideapad)[-_]laptop)"
IFACEMATCHES="(wlan[0-9]|eth[0-9])"
DMESGMATCHES="(firmware|[nN]etwork|sdio|SDIO)"
NMPROFMATCHES="\(\[connection\]\|id=\|type=\|permissions=\|autoconnect=\|\[802-11-wireless\]\|\[wifi\]\|ssid=\|bssid=\|mac-address\(-blacklist\)\?=\|mtu=\|\[802-1x\]\|[[:graph:]]*ca-certs\?=\|\[ipv[46]\]\|method=\)"

DMESGEXCL="apparmor|(cfg|mac)80211"
MODINFOINCL="filename|license|description|depends|retpoline|intree|name|vermagic|parm"
MODPROBEXCL="(alsa-base|blacklist-(firewire|framebuffer|modem|oss|watchdog)|fglrx|nvidia|fbdev|bumblebee)"
PMUTILSEXCL="/etc/pm/(power.d/(95hdparm-apm|intel-audio-powersave|sata_alpm)|sleep.d/(10_grub-common|10_unattended-upgrades.*|novatel_3g.*))"

NETMGRNAMES=("NetworkManager" "Wicd" "ConnMan")
NETMGRPATHS=("/usr/sbin/NetworkManager" "/usr/sbin/wicd" "/usr/sbin/connmand")
DEC2BI=({0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1})
DEC2HEX=($(printf "%02x " {0..255}))

export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"

if [ -t 0 ]; then
    DIALOGAPP="terminal"
    DIALOGBREAK=" "
    TERMOUT="yes"
elif [ -x /usr/bin/zenity ]; then
    DIALOGAPP="zenity"
    DIALOGBREAK="\n"
elif [ -x /usr/bin/kdialog ]; then
    DIALOGAPP="kdialog"
    DIALOGBREAK="\n"
else
    exit 1
fi

if [ -t 0 ]; then
    SUDO="sudo"
elif [ -x /usr/bin/pkexec ]; then
    SUDO="pkexec"
elif [ -x /usr/bin/gksudo ]; then
    SUDO="gksudo"
    GKSUDO="yes"
elif [ -x /usr/bin/kdesudo ]; then
    SUDO="kdesudo"
    KDESUDO="yes"
    KDESUDOCMT=" needs administrative privileges. Please enter your password."
fi

dialog_info () {
    case $DIALOGAPP in
    terminal)
        printf "%b\n" "$1"
        ;;
    zenity)
        zenity --info --text="$1"
        ;;
    kdialog)
        kdialog --msgbox "$1"
        ;;
    esac
}

dialog_error () {
    case $DIALOGAPP in
    terminal)
        printf "%b\n" "$1" >&2
        ;;
    zenity)
        zenity --error --text="$1"
        ;;
    kdialog)
        kdialog --error "$1"
        ;;
    esac
}

dialog_question () {
    case $DIALOGAPP in
    terminal)
        local INPUT
        read -r -p "$1 [Y/n]: " INPUT
        echo "${INPUT,,}"
        ;;
    zenity)
        zenity --question --text="$1" || echo "no"
        ;;
    kdialog)
        kdialog --yesno "$1" || echo "no"
        ;;
    esac
}

ip6-mac () {
    for MAC in "$@"; do
    OCT1BI=${DEC2BI[0x${MAC:0:2}]}
    OCT1BI7=$((${OCT1BI:6:1} - 1))
    OCT1BIM="${OCT1BI:0:6}${OCT1BI7#-}${OCT1BI:7}"
    IP6S+=${IP6S:+$'\n'}"${DEC2HEX[2#$OCT1BIM]}${MAC:3:2}:${MAC:6:2}ff:fe${MAC:9:2}:${MAC:12:2}${MAC:15:2}"
    done
    sed 's/\(^\|:\)0\+\([[:alnum:]]\)/\1\2/g;s/^\([0:]\+\)/\\(::\\|\1\\)/' <<< "$IP6S"
}

exec 3>&1 4>&2
exec 1> "$OUTPUTDIR/$FILEBASE.txt" || {
    dialog_error "${TERMOUT+\n}Cannot write output file in \"$OUTPUTDIR\",${DIALOGBREAK}trying in \"$OUTPUTDIRFB\" instead.${TERMOUT+\n}"
    OUTPUTDIR="$OUTPUTDIRFB"
    exec 1> "$OUTPUTDIR/$FILEBASE.txt" || {
    dialog_error "${TERMOUT+\n}Cannot write output file in \"$OUTPUTDIR\" either, aborting.${TERMOUT+\n}"
    exit 1
    }
}
exec 2>&1

printf "\n########## wireless info START ##########\n\n"
REPORTDATE=$(date +"%d %b %Y %H:%M %Z %z")
SCRIPTDATE=$(date -u -d "$SCRIPTDATE" +"%d %b %Y %H:%M %Z %z")
LASTBOOTDT=$(last -FRn 1 reboot | sed -n 's/.*system boot[ ]\+\(.\+\) - .*/\1/p')
LASTBOOTDT=$(date -d "$LASTBOOTDT" +"%d %b %Y %H:%M %Z %z")
printf "Report from: %s\n\n" "$REPORTDATE"
printf "Booted last: %s\n\n" "$LASTBOOTDT"
printf "Script from: %s\n" "$SCRIPTDATE"

printf "\n##### release ###########################\n\n"
lsb_release -idrc

printf "\n##### kernel ############################\n\n"
uname -srvmpio
echo
sed 's/root=[^ ]*//;s/[ ]\+/, /g;s/^BOOT_IMAGE=[^ ]*/Parameters:/' /proc/cmdline

printf "\n##### desktop ###########################\n\n"
if [ -n "$DESKTOP_SESSION" ]; then
    DESKTOP="$DESKTOP_SESSION"
else
    DESKTOP=$(sed -n 's/^Session=\(.\+\)$/\1/p' "$HOME/.dmrc")
    DESKDMRC=" (from ~/.dmrc)"
fi
if [ -n "$DESKTOP" ]; then
    if [ -f "/usr/share/xsessions/$DESKTOP.desktop" ]; then
    DESKTOP=$(sed -n 's/^Name=\(.\+\)$/\1/p' "/usr/share/xsessions/$DESKTOP.desktop")
    fi
    echo "${DESKTOP/ Session/}${DESKDMRC}"
else
    printf "\nCould not be determined.\n"
fi

printf "\n##### lspci #############################\n\n"
lspci -nnk | grep -iA 2 '^[^[:space:]].*net' | sed '/^--$/d; /^[^[:space:]]/ i\\'

printf "\n##### lsusb #############################\n\n"
lsusb

printf "\n##### PCMCIA card info ##################\n\n"
if [ -x /sbin/pccardctl ]; then
    pccardctl info
else
    echo "'pccardctl' is not installed (package \"pcmciautils\")."
fi

printf "\n##### rfkill ############################\n\n"
rfkill list all

printf "\n##### secure boot #######################\n\n"
if [ -x /usr/bin/mokutil ]; then
    mokutil --sb-state
else
    echo "'mokutil' is not installed (package \"mokutil\")."
fi

printf "\n##### lsmod #############################\n\n"
LSMOD=$(lsmod | egrep "(^|[[:punct:] ])($MODMATCHES|$LSMODMATCHES)[^[:punct:] ]*([[:punct:] ]|$)")
echo "$LSMOD"

printf "\n##### interfaces ########################\n\n"
for IFACESFILE in $(find /etc/network/interfaces{,.d} -type f 2> /dev/null | sort); do
    IFACESFLCNT=$(sed '/^#/d;s/^wpa-psk [[:graph:]]\+/wpa-psk <WPA key removed>/' $IFACESFILE)
    if [ -n "$IFACESFLCNT" ]; then
    printf "[%s]\n%s\n\n" "$IFACESFILE" "$IFACESFLCNT"
    fi
done

printf "\n##### ifconfig ##########################\n\n"
if [ -x /bin/ip ]; then
    IFCONFIG=$(ip address show)
elif [ -x /sbin/ifconfig ]; then
    IFCONFIG=$(ifconfig -a)
else
    echo "'ip' is not installed (package \"iproute2\")."
fi
echo "$IFCONFIG"
IFCONFIG=$(sed -n '1h; 1!H; ${g;s/\n /\\ /g;p}' <<< "$IFCONFIG")
IFACESETH=($(sed -n 's#^[0-9]\+: \([^ :]\+\):.* link/ether.*#\1#p; s/^\([^ :]\+\):\?.* \(Link encap:Ethernet\|ether\).*/\1/p' <<< "$IFCONFIG"))
if (( ${#IFACESETH[@]} > 0 )); then
    IFETHMATCHES=${IFACESETH[@]}
    IFACEMATCHES="($IFACEMATCHES|(${IFETHMATCHES// /|}))"
fi

printf "\n##### iwconfig ##########################\n\n"
iwconfig

printf "\n##### route #############################\n\n"
if [ -x /bin/ip ]; then
    ip route show
elif [ -x /sbin/route ]; then
    route -n
else
    echo "'ip' is not installed (package \"iproute2\")."
fi

printf "\n##### resolv.conf #######################\n\n"
stat -c "[%a %U %N]" /etc/resolv.conf
grep -v '^#' /etc/resolv.conf

printf "\n##### network managers ##################\n\n"
printf "Installed:\n\n"
for NETMGRNR in "${!NETMGRPATHS[@]}"; do
    if [ -f "${NETMGRPATHS[$NETMGRNR]}" ]; then
    NETMGRINST+=("${NETMGRNAMES[$NETMGRNR]}")
    fi
done
printf "\t%s\n" "${NETMGRINST[@]:-None found.}"
NETMGRMATCHES=${NETMGRPATHS[@]/#*\//|}
NETMGRMATCHES=${NETMGRMATCHES// |/|}
NETMGRMATCHES="(${NETMGRMATCHES#|})"
printf "\nRunning:\n\n"
ps -ef | egrep "( |/)$NETMGRMATCHES($| )" || printf "\tNone found.\n"

printf "\n##### NetworkManager info ###############\n\n"
if [ -x /usr/bin/nm-tool ]; then
    nm-tool
elif [ -x /usr/bin/nmcli ]; then
    nmcli -f all device show | sed '/^GENERAL.DEVICE:[ ]\+lo$/,/^$/d; /^AP\[[0-9]\+\]\./d'
    echo
    nmcli -f SSID,BSSID,MODE,CHAN,FREQ,RATE,SIGNAL,BARS,SECURITY,ACTIVE,IN-USE device wifi list
else
    echo "NetworkManager is not installed (package \"network-manager\")."
fi

printf "\n##### NetworkManager.state ##############\n\n"
"$SUDO" cat -s /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state

printf "\n##### NetworkManager config #############\n\n"
for NMCONFFILE in $(find /{etc,usr/lib}/NetworkManager/{NetworkManager.conf,conf.d} -name "*.conf" 2> /dev/null | sort); do
    NMCONFCNT=$(egrep -v '^(#|$)' $NMCONFFILE)
    if [ -n "$NMCONFCNT" ]; then
    printf "[[%s]]\n%s\n\n" "$NMCONFFILE" "$NMCONFCNT"
    fi
done

printf "\n##### NetworkManager profiles ###########\n\n"
if [ -d /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections ]; then
    if [ -n "$SUDO" ]; then
    trap "" 2 3
    NMPROFILES=$(find /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec $SUDO${GKSUDO+ -D grep --}${KDESUDO+ -d --comment "<b>grep</b>$KDESUDOCMT" --} grep -vH '^$' {} +) && SUDOSUCCESS="yes" || SUDOSUCCESS="no"
    trap 2 3
    if [ "$SUDOSUCCESS" = "yes" ]; then
        ORIGIFS="$IFS"
        IFS=$'\n'
        for NMWLPRFFILE in $(sed -n 's/^\(.\+\):type=\(802-11-wireless\|wifi\).*$/\1/p' <<< "$NMPROFILES"); do
        NMWLPRFFLPERMS=$(stat -c "%a %U" "$NMWLPRFFILE")
        NMWLPROFILE=($(sed -n "s;^$NMWLPRFFILE:\($NMPROFMATCHES.*\)$;\1 |;p" <<< "$NMPROFILES"))
        NMWLPROFSOUT+="[[$NMWLPRFFILE]] ($NMWLPRFFLPERMS)"$'\n'"${NMWLPROFILE[@]}"$'\n\n'
        done
        IFS="$ORIGIFS"
        sed 's# | \[#\n\[#g;s#\] |#\]#g;s/ |$//' <<< "$NMWLPROFSOUT" | sed '/^\[[^]]*\]$/d'
    else
        printf "\nAcquisition of admin privileges failed.\n"
    fi
    else
    echo "No way to acquire admin privileges found."
    fi
else
    echo "No NetworkManager profiles found."
fi

printf "\n##### Netplan config ####################\n\n"
for NPLANFILE in $(find /{lib,etc,run}/netplan -name "*.yaml" 2> /dev/null | sort); do
    NPLANFLCNT=$(egrep -v '^(#|$)' $NPLANFILE)
    if [ -n "$NPLANFLCNT" ]; then
    printf "[%s]\n%s\n\n" "$NPLANFILE" "$NPLANFLCNT"
    fi
done

printf "\n##### iw reg get ########################\n\n"
if [ -x /sbin/iw ]; then
    if IWREGGET=$(iw reg get 2>&1) && [ -f /etc/timezone ]; then
    REGION=$(cat /etc/timezone)
    printf "Region: %s (based on set time zone)\n\n" "$REGION"
    fi
    echo "$IWREGGET"
else
    echo "'iw' is not installed (package \"iw\")."
fi

printf "\n##### iwlist channels ###################\n\n"
if [ -x /sbin/iwlist ]; then
    iwlist chan
else
    echo "'iwlist' is not installed (package \"wireless-tools\")."
fi

printf "\n##### iwlist scan #######################\n\n"
if [ -x /sbin/iwlist ]; then
    if [ -n "$SUDO" ]; then
    trap "" 2 3
    IWLISTSCAN=$($SUDO${KDESUDO+ -d} iwlist scan) && SUDOSUCCESS="yes" || SUDOSUCCESS="no"
    trap 2 3
    if [ "$SUDOSUCCESS" = "yes" ]; then
        if [[ $IWLISTSCAN = *Frequency:* ]]; then
        printf "Channel occupancy:\n\n"
        grep '^[ ]*Frequency:' <<< "$IWLISTSCAN" | sort | uniq -c | sed 's/^[ ]\+\([ ][0-9]\+\)[ ]\+/     \1   APs on   /'
        echo
        fi
        grep -v '^[ ]*IE: Unknown:' <<< "$IWLISTSCAN"
    else
        printf "\nAcquisition of admin privileges failed.\n"
    fi
    else
    echo "No way to acquire admin privileges found."
    fi
else
    echo "'iwlist' is not installed (package \"wireless-tools\")."
fi

printf "\n##### module infos ######################\n\n"
MODULES=$(egrep -o "^$MODMATCHES[^ ]*" <<< "$LSMOD")
for MODULE in $MODULES; do
    MODINFO=$(modinfo $MODULE | egrep -i "^$MODINFOINCL:")
    printf "[%s]\n%s\n\n" "$MODULE" "$MODINFO"
done

printf "\n##### module parameters #################\n\n"
for MODULE in $MODULES; do
    if [ -d /sys/module/$MODULE/parameters ]; then
    MODPARAMS=$(grep -H '^[[:graph:]]' /sys/module/$MODULE/parameters/* | sed 's#^.*/##;s/:/: /')
    printf "[%s]\n%s\n\n" "$MODULE" "$MODPARAMS"
    fi
done

printf "\n##### /etc/modules ######################\n\n"
grep -v '^#' /etc/modules

printf "\n##### modprobe options ##################\n\n"
for MODPROBEFILE in $(find /etc/modprobe.{conf,d} -name "*.conf" -regextype posix-egrep -not -regex ".*$MODPROBEXCL.*" 2> /dev/null | sort); do
    MODPROBEOPTS=$(egrep -v '^(#|$)' $MODPROBEFILE)
    if [ -n "$MODPROBEOPTS" ]; then
    printf "[%s]\n%s\n\n" "$MODPROBEFILE" "$MODPROBEOPTS"
    fi
done

printf "\n##### rc.local ##########################\n\n"
grep -v '^#' /etc/rc.local

printf "\n##### pm-utils ##########################\n\n"
for PMUTILSFILE in $(find /etc/pm/*.d \( -type f -o -type l \) -regextype posix-egrep -not -regex "$PMUTILSEXCL" | sort); do
    PMUTFLCONT=$(egrep -v '^(#|$)' $PMUTILSFILE)
    if [ -n "$PMUTFLCONT" ]; then
    PMUTFLPERMS=$(stat -c "%a %U" $PMUTILSFILE)
    printf "[%s] (%s)\n%s\n\n" "$PMUTILSFILE" "$PMUTFLPERMS" "$PMUTFLCONT"
    fi
done

printf "\n##### udev rules ########################\n\n"
for UDEVRLFILE in $(find /etc/udev/rules.d -name "*net*.rules" | sort); do
    UDEVRULES=$(grep -B1 '^[^#]' $UDEVRLFILE | egrep -v '^(--)?$')
    if [ -n "$UDEVRULES" ]; then
    printf "[%s]\n%s\n\n" "$UDEVRLFILE" "$UDEVRULES"
    fi
done

printf "\n##### dmesg #############################\n\n"
"$SUDO" dmesg | tail -n 100 | egrep "[[:punct:] ]($MODMATCHES|$IFACEMATCHES|$DMESGMATCHES)[^[:punct:] ]*[[:punct:] ]" | egrep -v "$DMESGEXCL" | uniq -cf 2 | sed 's/^[ ]\+1[ ]\+//;s/^[ ]\+\([0-9]\+\)[ ]\+\(.\+\)$/\2 (repeated \1 times)/'

printf "\n########## wireless info END ############\n\n"

exec 2>&4 4>&-
exec 1>&3 3>&-

##### MAC address masking #####

RESULTS=$(cat -s "$OUTPUTDIR/$FILEBASE.txt")$'\n'

ORIGIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'

IFACESIDS=($(sed -n "/\([[:alnum:]]\{2\}:\)\{5\}[[:alnum:]]\{2\}/ {/\(00:\)\{5\}00/! {s/^[0-9]\+: \([^ :]\+\):.*/'\1'/p; s/^\([^ :]\+\):\? .*/'\1'/p}}" <<< "$IFCONFIG"))
IFACESMACS=($(sed -n '/\(00:\)\{5\}00/! s#.*\(HWaddr\|link/[^ ]\+\|ether\) \(\([[:alnum:]]\{2\}:\)\{5\}[[:alnum:]]\{2\}\).*#\2#p' <<< "$IFCONFIG"))
IFACESIP6S=($(ip6-mac "${IFACESMACS[@]}"))

WLAPSIWLIDS=($(sed -n "/^[ ]*Cell [0-9]\+/,/^[ ]*ESSID:/ {/^[ ]*Cell [0-9]\+/h; /^[ ]*ESSID:/ {H;g;s/^[ ]*Cell 0\?\([0-9]\+\).*ESSID:\"\(.*\)\"$/'\2' [AC\1]/p}}" <<< "$IWLISTSCAN"))
WLAPSIWLMACS=($(sed -n 's/^[ ]*Cell [0-9]\+.*Address: \([^ ]\+\)/\1/p' <<< "$IWLISTSCAN"))
WLAPSIWLIP6S=($(ip6-mac "${WLAPSIWLMACS[@]}"))

WLAPSNMRAW=$(sed -n '/^##### NetworkManager info #####/,/^##### / {/^[ ]*Wireless Access Points/,/^$/ {/Wireless Access Points/d;s/^[ ]\+\*\?//;s/:[ ]\+/\t/;p}; /^SSID[ ]\+BSSID[ ]\+/,/^$/ {/^SSID[ ]\{2,\}BSSID[ ]\{2,\}/d;s/[ ]\{2,\}/\t/;p}}' <<< "$RESULTS")
WLAPSNMIDS=($(awk -F '\t' '{print "'\''" $1 "'\''"}' <<< "$WLAPSNMRAW"))
WLAPSNMMACS=($(grep -o '\([[:alnum:]]\{2\}:\)\{5\}[[:alnum:]]\{2\}' <<< "$WLAPSNMRAW"))
WLAPSNMIP6S=($(ip6-mac "${WLAPSNMMACS[@]}"))

IFS="$ORIGIFS"

for IFACENR in "${!IFACESMACS[@]}"; do
    MACMASKSED+="s;${IFACESMACS[$IFACENR]};<MAC ${IFACESIDS[$IFACENR]} [IF$(($IFACENR + 1))]>;I;"
    MACMASKSED+=" /${IFACESIP6S[$IFACENR]}/ s;${IFACESIP6S[$IFACENR]/#\\(::/\(};<IP6 ${IFACESIDS[$IFACENR]} [IF$(($IFACENR + 1))]>;I;"
    IFACEMACC=${IFACESMACS[$IFACENR]//:/}
    if [[ ${IFACESIDS[$IFACENR],,} =~ ${IFACEMACC,,} ]]; then
    MACMASKSED+="s;\(${IFACESIDS[$IFACENR]:1:3}\)$IFACEMACC;\1<IF from MAC [IF$(($IFACENR + 1))]>;Ig;"
    fi
done

for WLAPIWLNR in "${!WLAPSIWLMACS[@]}"; do
    MACMASKSED+="s;${WLAPSIWLMACS[$WLAPIWLNR]};<MAC ${WLAPSIWLIDS[$WLAPIWLNR]}>;I;"
    MACMASKSED+=" /${WLAPSIWLIP6S[$WLAPIWLNR]}/ s;${WLAPSIWLIP6S[$WLAPIWLNR]/#\\(::/\(};<IP6 ${WLAPSIWLIDS[$WLAPIWLNR]}>;I;"
done

for WLAPNMNR in "${!WLAPSNMMACS[@]}"; do
    MACMASKSED+="s;${WLAPSNMMACS[$WLAPNMNR]};<MAC ${WLAPSNMIDS[$WLAPNMNR]} [AN$(($WLAPNMNR + 1))]>;I;"
    MACMASKSED+=" /${WLAPSNMIP6S[$WLAPNMNR]}/ s;${WLAPSNMIP6S[$WLAPNMNR]/#\\(::/\(};<IP6 ${WLAPSNMIDS[$WLAPNMNR]} [AN$(($WLAPNMNR + 1))]>;I;"
done

sed "$MACMASKSED /\([[:alnum:]]\{2\}:\)\{6,\}/! s/\([[:alnum:]]\{2\}:\)\{5\}[[:alnum:]]\{2\}/<MAC address>/g" <<< "$RESULTS" > "$OUTPUTDIR/$FILEBASE.txt"

##### The End #####

dialog_info "${TERMOUT+\n}Results saved in \"$OUTPUTDIR/$FILEBASE.txt\".${TERMOUT+\n}"

if (( $(stat -c %s "$OUTPUTDIR/$FILEBASE.txt") > 19968 )); then
    tar -czf "$OUTPUTDIR/$FILEBASE.tar.gz" -C "$OUTPUTDIR" "$FILEBASE.txt" && \
    dialog_info "Results also archived in \"$OUTPUTDIR/$FILEBASE.tar.gz\",${DIALOGBREAK}as they exceed the 19.5 kB size limit for \".txt\" attachments${DIALOGBREAK}on the Ubuntu Forums.${TERMOUT+\n}" || \
    dialog_error "Results exceed the 19.5 kB size limit for \".txt\" attachments${DIALOGBREAK}on the Ubuntu Forums, but archive could not be created.${TERMOUT+\n}"
fi

if [ -x /usr/bin/pastebinit ] && ping -nc 3 -w 6 -i 0.2 paste.ubuntu.com > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    PASTEBIN=$(dialog_question "Do you also want to post them${DIALOGBREAK}to your default 'pastebinit' provider?")
    if [[ ! $PASTEBIN =~ ^no?$ ]]; then
    PASTERESULT=$(pastebinit -i "$OUTPUTDIR/$FILEBASE.txt" -f text 2>&1) && PASTESUCCESS="yes"
    if [ "$PASTESUCCESS" = "yes" ]; then
        dialog_info "${TERMOUT+\n}Pastebin successful:\n\n${PASTERESULT}${TERMOUT+\n}"
    else
        if [ -n "$PASTERESULT" ]; then
        dialog_error "${TERMOUT+\n}Pastebin failed, error message is:\n\n${PASTERESULT}${TERMOUT+\n}"
        else
        dialog_error "${TERMOUT+\n}Pastebin failed, no error message given.${TERMOUT+\n}"
        fi
    fi
    else
    echo
    fi
fi
```

**EDIT:** I see that it says "Helpers: chili555" at the top, and @chili555 is an AskUbuntu user that greatly helped me a lot on speeding up my network connection.

Is the file safe to delete?

Comment: The answers below are quite correct. It is safe to delete!

Comment: @chili555 Wow, I'm glad you saw this. Is the script still useful even if I reverted the experimental things I did on this post (https://askubuntu.com/a/1386219/1200423)? E.g. is it still useful or is it completely useless since there is nothing using it? P.S. I used this script and it is really good for when I want to get info on my wireless! EDIT: Now I realize that this comment is useless since I realized that I can use this script any time I want to for wireless info :P

Comment: It is genius! It is always useful! Seriously, it is used to gather all, hopefully, details that we can use to diagnose wireless problems. It is faster and easier than asking for one or two data points at a time and then, depending on the result, asking for a few more. Let's just get all the details we can in one clear report. Once your wireless is working, it has no further practical use.

Comment: @chili555 Alright. I'm going to keep it since it's cool (lol) and in case I have any problems in the future. thanks for the clarification

Comment: LOL! Call on us at any time we can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a quite popular script, created by some Ubuntu Forums users, and is used to collect relevant info for troubleshooting wireless connection issues.

The script can be found here: https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info

The script does the following:

> - Creates the file `wireless-info.txt` at the location it is run from.
> - Additionally creates the archive `wireless-info.tar.gz` if the file exceeds 19.5 kB in size.
> - Masks all sensitive info, like MAC addresses and WPA/WEP keys, automatically in a meaningful way.
> - Offers to post the results to your default `pastebinit` provider if the program is installed, and a sufficiently reliable internet connection is available.

It's totally safe to delete, as it doesn't do anything more than collect this information.

Comment: Thanks! I use this script to get information on my wifi, but I never knew where it came from and wanted to make sure that it was what I thought

Answer (score 3):

Reading the comment section at the top tells us that it's a script to gather information for troubleshooting purposes:

```
# This script gathers the infos necessary for troubleshooting a wireless
# connection and saves them in a text file, wrapping it in an archive if it
# exceeds the 19.5 kB size limit for ".txt" attachments on the Ubuntu Forums.
```

If you don't need the script anymore, you can delete it.

In the future, pay attention to *where* a file resides in your home folder.  For example, a file in the `~/Downloads` folder can be deleted if you don't need or want it anymore.

Comment: Thanks, Nmath. It was just in my home folder and not in a subdirectory.

Comment: Ah, there shouldn't be any important files hanging out directly under your user's home folder.  Just for organizational purposes, it's probably not great to save files there to begin with.

Comment: Oh. I don't even know why it was there in the first place...I never knew I added it